# Webcamera and microphone not working after upgrade from 10.04, microsoft VX-1000

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, webcam, skype

I have also tried `env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype` 
Skype recognizes the camera, but when I press test, only a black screen.

Cheese is working fine, the microphone is listed to be input in the sound settings, but no response.

Everything worked on 10.04, it seems like it's not supported yet?

Answer (score 1):

Are you now using Ubuntu 12.04?
Then you should use:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

as the `libv4l` folder's location is changed in 12.04 w.r.t. previous ubuntu distributions.
I'm currently searching for a microphone solution as well.